# Is there some function to sort sheet tabs in an Excel file?

Tags: excel, office365

I want to sort the sheets tabs in an Excel file in alphabetical order without any VBA.

No function found that can do the trick many VBAs but don't want to use VBA for this particular problem. This problem is for some file that is frequently used by many users VBAs can be tricky for all

Comment: This is only possible programmatically.